# Баг с повторной регистрацией

Tags: дефект, регистрация

Чтобы задать анонимный вопрос, написал текст и указал e-mail через «+» (someone+suffix@example.com), дабы не заводить новую почту. Закрыл браузер, почистил кеш и Cookie. В надежде ответить автору ответа зашёл в почтовый сервис, чтобы найти письмо с предложением пройти регистрацию до конца, но не обнаружил его, совсем позабыв, что настраивал фильтры для автосортировки по каталогам. Решив проверить гипотезу о том, что при обычной регистрации с таким же ящиком вопрос должен автоматически добавиться в профиль, создал новый аккаунт, но подтвердить сразу не получилось — не заметил письма, ведь оно тоже пришло в другую папку. Заметил только после того, как запросил восстановление пароля. Удаляю профиль, пытаюсь перейти по ссылке из самого первого письма, привязанного к вопросу, система предлагает ввести пароль. Что она выдаёт в ответ, видно на картинке ниже. При попытке восстановить пароль письмо приходит, но результат такой же.

Немного сумбурно получилось. Вот алгоритм воспроизведения проблемы:

1. Анонимно задать вопрос, указав e-mail.
2. Почистить Cookie.
3. Зарегистрировать новый аккаунт на ту же почту.
4. Удалить новый аккаунт.
5. Попытаться завершить регистрацию аккаунта с вопросом, перейдя по ссылке из первого сообщения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для большей ясности привожу хронологию писем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что теперь нет возможности ответить человеку в роли автора вопроса. Как-то так.

Простейшее решение — запретить регистрацию на уже использовавшийся адрес.